# Change owner of Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

How do you change the owner of an Azure AD directory? I have two accounts and see the tenant/directory I want listed as a directory. I want to transfer the ownership to the other account.

**UPDATE**
Ok. More information. I had one subscription and created 3 B2C directories. Each time I linked to the subscription, which is part of the process. Apparently you cannot have more than 1 B2C tenant linked to a subscription, so the other two were left "stranded" outside of a subscription. So I had to create a new subscription and associate the B2C directory with it, so it was a resource of the subscription. Then I used IAM to add the 2nd Azure account as a co-administrator of the subscription. I transferred the subscription to the 2nd Azure account.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest authority in Azure AD is `Global administrator`. If you want to transfer ownership to another user, you only need to give that user `Global administrator`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had a challenge with this. There was non way for me to get my 2nd account in the B2C tenant. I tried all three methods, but there did not seem any way to associate the actual Azure account owner with the identity in B2C even when using email.